# Apple Developer and Enterprise Programs together

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

We are already signed up with an iOS Developer Program. Now is it possible for us to sign up for an iOS Enterprise Program?

I am asking this because when we develop apps we need to install the app to multiple iPhones/iPads for testing purposes. Since the developer program has a limitation of 100 UDIDs, we are thinking of using an enterprise program to distribute the test builds.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have both.

We are in the verification process of an Enterprise account currently - the main registration difference is that your company will need to have a DUNS number. (Dun & Bradstreet)

Our application has been in limbo with Apple now, as the DUNS we supplied was not listed on their database - Apple use a particular dataset which only lists organisations that have published financials, so if your company has not done this then you should inform Apple of this during the application process, so that they look you up in the correct database.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how big of a company we are talking about, but are you sure 100 devices that can be tested on arent enough?

the eneterprise programm is normally for apps that are just developed for the company itself and that will never go onto the app store..

but otherwise if there is a need for a lot of testers it should be possible

i myself never was part of the enterprise programm so you should probaly wait for some more opinions anyhow^^

Comment: Actually the app will be tested by our clients, so i am afraid the 100 will not last much longer. As i stated earlier, if we can have an enterprise program too, the test releases can be made through it and the app-store release through the developer program.

Comment: i mean yeah depends on how much clients, but if you keep about 20 for your company and give each client another 3 or so then there will still be enough for about 30 clients.. so yeah if you think you need more then go for the enterprise.. or start out with the developer and see how far you get, maybe not all clients want to test anyhow and they jsut want to wait for teh release...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking to do the something, and just get done talking to apple support yesterday. If you want to join both program, you will need difference Apple ID, which is easy to do, just sign up with another email address.

And the enterprise program is used for in-house app only which means you are not supposed to test the app on devices not belong to the company or employees of company.

Answer (score 0):

The enterprise account is definitely *not* suitable for this.

The enterprise account is *only* for companies distributing apps within their own company. The account terms say that you are not allowed to distribute outside your company at all, and you are responsible for this. Within your company, you can do what you want.

I'd also check if the testing terms have changed during WWDC.